# Combining media query statements

Tags: sass

I'm creating a media query helper with SASS. I need your help getting the `medium` breakpoint working.

Right now it's only printing the max-width. Any ideas why?

```
$breakpoints: (
  small: ( max-width:  767px ),
  medium: (min-width: 768px ) and ( max-width:  991px ), // <--
  large: ( min-width: 1200px )
);

@mixin respond-to($name) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $name) {
    @media #{inspect(map-get($breakpoints, $name))} {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else {
    @warn "no match found in breakpoint map";
  }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure what you're trying to achieve.but this article(https://medium.com/front-end-developers/the-solution-to-media-queries-in-sass-5493ebe16844#.fumf11o62) will solve sass's mediaquery duplication problem and it'll enhance your workflow and save alot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sass tries to calculate boolean value of `(min-width: 768px ) and ( max-width:  991px )` and gets error. So you should set breakpoints as strings.

Sass:

```
$breakpoints: (
  small:  '( max-width: 767px )',
  medium: '( min-width: 768px ) and ( max-width:  991px )',
  large:  '( min-width: 1200px )'
);

@mixin respond-to($name) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $name) {
    @media #{map-get($breakpoints, $name)} {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @warn "no match found in breakpoint map";
  }
}

a {
  @include respond-to(medium) {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Css output:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  a {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Sassmeister [**demo**](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/13d8623ecbe64e2f344cb404afd1bcf4).